# SwiftUI + Firebase - Listener not listening for changes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I've set up a listener, but it doesn't seem to be changing according to changes in the data. The flow is the following:

1. If `userCustomHabit` is empty, user sees a button
2. When clicked, user can enter text in a `TextField` from a sheet to add to `userCustomHabit` (an array of strings)
3. Now that `userCustomHabit` is not empty, they should see something else

However, the problem I'm seeing is that `userCustomHabits` isn't updating in the view itself even though it is updating in the Firestore database.

Anyone know why this is? Included code below:

**View**

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel = RoutinesViewModel()

Group {
  if self.viewModel.userCustomHabits.isEmpty {
    Button(action: {
      self.showCreateSheet.toggle()
    }) {
      Text("Create your own habits")
        .font(Font.custom("Roboto-Regular", size: 20))
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 88/100, height: 200)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .background(Color.init(UIColor.systemGray5))
        .cornerRadius(40)
        .overlay(
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [20]))
            .foregroundColor(Color.init(UIColor.systemGray3))
        )
    }
  }
  else {
    // Something else
  }
}
.onAppear(perform: self.viewModel.newHabitsListener)
```

**Sheet**

```swift
VStack {
  TextField("Enter text", text: $enteredText)
  Button("Add Habit") {
    self.viewModel.createNewHabits(newHabit: self.enteredText)
  }
}
```

**View Model**

```swift
@Published var userCustomHabits = [String]()

func newHabitsListener() {
  db.collection("users").document(currUser?.uid ?? "").addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
    guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
      print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
      return
    }
    guard let data = document.data() else {
      print("Document data was empty.")
      return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.userCustomHabits = data["userCustomHabits"] as! [String]
    }
  }
}

func createNewHabits(newHabit: String) {
  db.collection("users").document(currUser?.uid ?? "").updateData(["userCustomHabits": FieldValue.arrayUnion([newHabit])])
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `viewModel.createHabits`, as well as how you bind to the viewModel? Also, you might want to remove `includeMetadataChanges` if you don't need the meta data.

Comment: Added a few things. Not sure if this is what you were asking for. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code for how you bind to the view model in your view?

Comment: I just added. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Peter - would you be able to help me here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @glothais-kwl - was busy watching WWDC videos :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with your code a bit (since the code sample is incomplete, I had to make a few assumptions), and it seems like you might never have created the document you're writing to in the first place.

`updateData` only updates *existing* documents (see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)). To create a new document, use `setData` (see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document))

When changing your code form `updateData` to `setData`, the listener kicked in as expected.

However, it might be better to add a sub-collection `customHabits` to each user document. This way, adding new habits is as simple as adding a new document, which also makes querying a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Peter! Unfortunately, the document did exist. As I mentioned, it updates the user document successfully, but the listener just doesn't seem to catch the update.

Comment: So, it looks like the listener IS working to an extent. When I manually add data into userCustomHabit from Firestore, I can see print statements I placed in newHabitsListener that show me userCustomHabits is now updated. However, when I put a button in the View to see what self.viewModel.userCustomHabits is, I see that it's an empty string for some reason. So listener is listening, but not updating the userCustomHabits itself somehow?